Copy Excel Range with merged cells into Word as Table using VBA
I want to copy a range having merged cells from Excel to Word. I am also hiding a few columns I don't need in Word. My code works fine except that the merged cells become unmerged. How can I preserve the merged cells?
     For Each boqWs In boqWb.Worksheets
                If InStr(1, selectedTabNames, boqWs.Name) > 0 Then
                    lastRow = boqWs.Cells(boqWs.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
                    ' Define the range to copy (only visible columns)
                    Set boqRng = boqWs.Range("A1:N" & lastRow)
                    ' hide columns in BOQ that dont need to be copied
                    boqWs.Range("C:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    boqWs.Range("G:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    boqWs.Range("I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    boqWs.Range("K:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    
                    ' Copy visible columns
                    boqRng.Copy
                    
                    ' Paste into Word as a table
                    With rng
                        .PasteExcelTable False, False, True ' Paste the table with formatting
                        .Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior 2 'wdAutoFitWindow
                    End With
                    
                     ' Clear The Clipboard
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    
                    ' Unhide columns if necessary
                    boqWs.Range("C:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    boqWs.Range("G:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    boqWs.Range("I:I").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    boqWs.Range("K:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    ' Move to the next paragraph for subsequent additions
                    Set rng = rng.Tables(1).Range
                    rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                    rng.InsertParagraphAfter
                
                    rng.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

                End If
        Next boqWs


Where are the cells unmerged? In Excel or Word? (I'm assuming the end result is a table in Word)

You are right - the end result is a table in Word doc and the cells are copied without any merging in Word. Nothing changes in Excel as expected, but I'd expect the Word table to show the same merging as in Excel

I believe you need to use .PasteExcelTable False, False, False to keep the cells merged

Looks like it worked, I will do some more testing and confirm, thanks
